# Bootstrap Tooltip changes from top to bottom when it reaches the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I'm working with tooltip in the top position, the problem is that when I scroll and the tooltip is reaching the top of the window it changes its bottom position, which I do not want it to do, but keep it in position at all times higher.

If you start the code that I put in this question you will see that the tooltip is automatically displayed, and when you scroll down all the tooltip changes from top to bottom position which I do not want you to do, I want to keep it at all times top.

Thanks for the help.

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ placement: 'top', boundary: 'window'                 });
  $("#element").tooltip('show');
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn-secondary{
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="element" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</button>

<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `data-placement="top"`

try this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
 Tooltip on top
</button>
```